# How to manipulate special price-- only for frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to change the special price when it get displayed on the frontend.
so, if the special price is $25 then I want it to show $(100+25). How can I achieve this. I created a plugin which update the `afterGetPrice()` (works for regular price only).

Is there any way to change the special Price/tier price on the frontend only. (It must checkout with the updated price-- $125)

my `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
       <plugin name="change_product" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Model\Product" sortOrder="1" />
     </type>
 </config>
```

and `Plugin/Model/Product.php`

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Plugin\Model;

class Product
  {

     public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
     { 

       return $result * 2.25;
      }
   }
```

which display the product with the wanted price but this piece of code does not work if product has special price..I want to do the same for all price types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need this:

all you need to just copy the same function and change the name `afterGetSpecialPrice`:

```
public function afterGetSpecialPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{ 
   return $result * 2.25;
}
```

don't forget to run `setup:upgrade` command and `cache:clean`
good day :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your plugin already works. You are now trying to apply the plugin price change only for frontend. Try the below then, that should do just that

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class PricePlugin
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    public function __construct(
        State $state
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function afterGetPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price $price,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        if ($this->state->getAreaCode() === Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {
            $result += 100; //  charge for frontend user
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

in your case, change

```
public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
     { 

       return $result * 2.25;
      }
```

to

```
public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{ 
       if ($this->state->getAreaCode() === Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {
               $result * 2.25
            }

       return $result;
}
```

of course, add state dependency in your constructor like in my example

Comment: Hi @Herve thanks for the answer. I am a bit confuse now, do I need to create a new plugin file?

Comment: no your plugin file should be fine, update your question with it to be sure maybe. Put all your code just to be clear..

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: okay I am trying this.

Comment: please https://imgur.com/jDQcCHZ  visit this

Comment: sorry nit, It does become one to one and I have provided you sufficient help for now. Please accept if it helps.

Comment: thanks for your time and help @Herve. I appreciate.